# What happens if my task failed in middle in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Suppose I have a task scheduled in order,
task 1 > task 2 > task 3 > task 4 > task 5.
What happens if task 3 fails?
Does it run task 4 and task 5?

Comment: It depends on the `trigger_rule` that you have defined for the task 4 & task 5. Checkout [trigger-rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/concepts.html?highlight=trigger#trigger-rules)

Answer (score 0):

There is ***trigger_rule*** for all Operators which is ***all_success*** by default. So if you didn't change it, when task 3 fails, task 4 and task 5 don't run at all.
For more information see [this link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/concepts.html?highlight=trigger#trigger-rules)